# Click event function does not work on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angular

"The single option contains *ngFor and (click) event directives. *ngFor loop iterates an object using keyvalue pipe.Dropdown options show fine but it does not call the fucntion when I click on these options on chrome but works on firefox.

```
  subjects = {
    'cse': 'Computer Science',
    'eee': 'electrical and electronics engineering',
  };

  getSub(sub) {
     console.log(sub);
  }
```

```
<select>
   <option *ngFor="let item of subjects | keyvalue" (click)="getSub(item.key)">{{item.value}}</option>
</select>


Expected: I just expect to execute the getSub() function.
```

Comment: Try to remove `| keyvalue` and also use ending `"` after `subjects` and test again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use change event instead of click event and subscribe to the select element not the option

```
<select (change)="getSub($event.target.value)">
   <option>Not Selected</option>
   <option *ngFor="let item of subjects | keyvalue" [value]="item.key" >
     {{item.value}}
   </option>
</select>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-change)

Comment: It works fine. A big thanks to you specially for stackblitz demo. I just noticed this job and really.. it's really  helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot your closing quotes after the *ngFor, and before your (click) event attribute.

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let item of subjects | keyvalue" (click)="getSub(item.key)">{{item.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: sorry sir, I just re-wrote the codes. That's why I made a mistake. And this code completely works fine on firefox. Thanks sir.